# How to get rid of the virtual keyboard that appears in login screen on KDE Plasma Ubuntu?

Tags: plasma, onscreen-keyboard

I recently installed KDE Plasma Ubuntu and every time I log in my user account a virtual keyboard shows up on the screen covering half of if. I will never use that keyboard so how can i get rid of it?

Comment: I've never seen this with Kubuntu. Are you using Kubuntu?  Maybe you can post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: here is a link to an image I took with my phone because I also can't make screenshots=) https://drive.google.com/file/d/195dz_l0DYGGHRm_HGWVQvBpI0Vl0UYq6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For the purposes of diagnostics can you create a new user and see if the problem persists?  This will narrow down whether or not the problem is system wide or specific to your user. Maybe an errant config someplace

Comment: I did what you asked and the keyboard still shows up. I will try to change my GUI to the default one. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

A) First, you may try to add **Kubuntu desktop**,

`sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`

B) If adding Kubuntu-desktop does not work, you may try this;

i) Check `cat /etc/sddm.conf`. Make the file `sddm.conf` if it does not exit, i.e.

`sudo touch /etc/sddm.conf`

ii) If the file exists, change `InputMethod=` (yes, it should not be virtual keyboard). If you have made the file in the first step, add these lines (you may use `sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf`),

```
# Input method module
InputMethod=
```

iii) reboot

Comment: This worked, thanks! `kubuntu-desktop` was already installed. I had to create the `sddm.conf` file with the specified setting.

Answer (score 0):

cool!
That worked for me. I had installed kde-full on ubuntu desktop standard and I wanted to get rid of that keyboard-screen:

1. create sddm.conf (file did not exist before)
   sudo touch /etc/sddm.conf
2. Edit /etc/sddm.conf and enter the following line:
   InputMethod=
3. save and reboot - and - voila - keyboard gone